# Cascaded string split, pythonic way

Tags: python, python-2.7

Take for example this format from IANA: http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry

```
%%
Type: language
Subtag: aa
Description: Afar
Added: 2005-10-16
%%
Type: language
Subtag: ab
Description: Abkhazian
Added: 2005-10-16
Suppress-Script: Cyrl
%%
Type: language
Subtag: ae
Description: Avestan
Added: 2005-10-16
%%
```

Say I open the file:

```
import urllib
f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry")
all=f.read()
```

Normally you would do like this

```
lan=all.split("%%")
```

the iterate lan and `split("\n")` then iterate the result and split(":"), is there a way to to this in python in one batch without the iteration and the output still be like this:
`[[["Type","language"],["Subtag", "ae"],...]...]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a single comprehension:

```
raw = """\
%%
Type: language
Subtag: aa
Description: Afar
Added: 2005-10-16
%%
Type: language
Subtag: ab
Description: Abkhazian
Added: 2005-10-16
Suppress-Script: Cyrl
%%
Type: language
Subtag: ae
Description: Avestan
Added: 2005-10-16
%%"""


data = [
     dict(
         row.split(': ')
         for row in item_str.split("\n")
         if row  # required to avoid the empty lines which contained '%%'
     )
     for item_str in raw.split("%%") 
     if item_str  # required to avoid the empty items at the start and end
]
```

```
>>> data[0]['Added']
'2005-10-16'
```

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu: Just noticed this question was a year old. Oh well - happy to help

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any sense in trying to do this in a single pass, if the elements you are getting to after each split are semantically  diffent.

You could start by spliting by ":" -- that wold get you to the fine grained data - but what good would that be, if you wold not know were does this data belong?

That said, you could put all the levels of separation inside a generator, and have it yield
dictionary-objects with your data, ready for consunption:

```
def iana_parse(data):
    for record in data.split("%%\n"):
        # skip empty records at file endings:
        if not record.strip():
            continue
        rec_data = {}
        for line in record.split("\n"):
            key, value = line.split(":")
            rec_data[key.strip()] = value.strip()
        yield rec_data
```

It can be done as a one liner as you request in the comments - but as I commented back,
It could be written to fit as a single expression in one line. It took more time to write than the example above, and would be nearly impossible to maintain. The code in the example above unfolds the logic in a few lines of code, that are placed "out of the way" - i.e. not inline where you are deaing witht he actual data, providing readability and maintainability for both tasks.

That said, parsing as a structure of nested lists as you want can be done thus:

```
structure = [[[token.strip() for token in line.split(":")] for line in record.split("\n") ] for record in data.split("%%") if record.strip() ]
```

Comment: So is not posible to get it like this `[[["Type","language"],["Subtag", "ae"],...]...]` without iteratin it?

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu not really, besides if you call a function to generate this output for you it iterates internally, what is so bad about iteration?

Comment: It could be written to fit as a single expression in one line. It woudl take more time to write than the example above, and would be nearly impossible to maintain. The code in the example above unfolds the logic in a few lines of code, that are placed "out of the ay" - i.e. not inline where you are deaing witht he actual data, providing readability and maintainability for both tasks.

Comment: @jsbueno: +1 for guessing what is intended here and supplying a beautiful generator for it.

Comment: in the module I get this error:`File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in iana_parse
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
` which is the line with `key, value = line.split(":")`

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu: try [`partition`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=partition#str.partition) then, it always returns a three tuple. The new line 8 would read: `key, value = line.partition(':')[::2]` (or `key, _, value = line.partition(':')` but be wary of problems with the `i18n` module which binds `_` to its gettext function.

Answer (score 2):

[Regexes](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/re.html?highlight=match#re.split), but I don't see the point:

```
re.split('%%|:|\\n', string)
```

Here multiple patterns were chained using the or `|` operator.

Comment: But then you don't know when one record ends and the next begins, unless you hard-code a requirement that each record has to start with the `Type` field, for example. You also make it impossible to have a delimiter in a field value, which may not be a serious issue in this particular case (and/or you could require newlines on both sides of `%%` if you like).

Comment: @tripleee: how about splitting with lookahead patterns? I can do the same for delimiters (they would have to be escaped or you assume that one only takes the first delimiter). I could show you some regexes for this if you are interested, but you might just as well head over to the regex doc linked in the awnser. Besides, this was just an awnser to do what the user asked, I consider this approach highly inappropiate for parsing purposes. Even for csv files I consider it wiser to consume the fields one by one, this makes detecting escaped delimiters easier. (I know there is the `csv` module)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
ss = """%%
Type: language
Subtag: aa
Description: Afar
Added: 2005-10-16
%%
Type: language
Subtag: ab
Description: Abkhazian
Added: 2005-10-16
Suppress-Script: Cyrl
%%
Type: language
Subtag: ae
Description: Avestan
Added: 2005-10-16
"""
sss = ss.splitlines(True) #List which looks like you're iterating over a file object


import itertools

output = []
for k,v in itertools.groupby(sss,lambda x: x.strip() == '%%'):
    if(k):  #Hit a '%%' record.  Need a new group.
        print "\nNew group:\n"
        current = {}
        output.append(current)
    else:   #just a regular record, write the data to our current record dict.
        for line in v:
            print line.strip()
            key,value = line.split(None,1)
            current[key] = value
```

One benefit of this answer is that it doesn't require you to read the entire file.  The whole expression is evaluated lazily.