# Python: Fastest way to find a string in an enumeration

Tags: python, string, search, python-2.7, enumeration

Parsed the [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry) subtag (see [Cascaded string split, pythonic way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12460634/1577343)) and made a list of 8600 tags:

```
tags= ['aa',
       'ab',
       'ae',
       'af',
       'ak',
       'am',
       'an',
       'ar',
       # ...
```

I want to check for example `mytag="ro"` if is in the list:
what is the fastest way to do that:

**First solution:**

```
if mytag in tags:
    print "found"
```

**Second solution:**

```
if mytag in Set(tags):
    print "found"
```

**Third solution:** Transform the list in a big string like: `'|aa|ab|ae|af|ak|am|an|ar|...'` and then see if string is in another string:

```
tags = '|aa|ab|ae|af|ak|am|an|ar|...'
if mytag in tags:
    print "found"
```

Is there another way? Which is the fastest, is this already measured, if not how can I benchmark myself (shoul I take a random element from the list or should I take the last and then test it, can someone provide python code for a 'chronometer')?

Comment: I _think_ a tuple is faster than a list. Then it only takes time to convert it once and then a lookup should speed up (of course, this only makes sense if you build it once and use it multiple times)

Comment: @Tichodroma comment in python is #

Comment: @javex Build it once, use it mutiple times

Comment: @Javex possibly but both have terrib efficiency for lookups, they each take O(N) while a set is almost always a constant O(1) lookup. Note to OP: checking mytag in set(tags) defeats the purpose of a set because you are constructing a new one each time. Make sure not to do this in your real code and initialize the set at the beginning only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I don't have access to the original string, any test would be biased. However, you asked for a chronometer ? Check the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module, designed to time some code snippets.

Note that if you use `IPython`, `%timeit` is a magic function that makes it a breeze to time the execution of a function, as illustrated below.

Some comments

- you should replace `Set` by `set`...
- construct your `set` and long string before running any test
- Taking a random element from your `tags` list is the way to go indeed.

---

As an example of use of `%timeit` in IPython:

```
tags = ['aa','ab','ae','af','ak','an','ar']
tags_set = set(tags)
tags_str = "|".join(tags)

%timeit 'ro' in tags
1000000 loops, best of 3: 223 ns per loop
%timeit 'ro' in tags_set
1000000 loops, best of 3: 73.5 ns per loop
%timeit 'ro' in tags_str
1000000 loops, best of 3: 98.1 ns per loop
```

Comment: I tried this with 65780 elemnts in the list and result was 843us (List), 54.6ns (Set), 264us (Str). So I would definitely go for sets.

Comment: I get the error  %timeit 'ro' in tags
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It's IPython Syntax for the `%timeit` in the console.

Comment: @ChristianWitts I already managed to make it work, now I use %cpaste and put all the code,

Comment: @yilmazhuseyin I tried it with the IANA tags, and got same results, set first, string second, list last, you can see my answer.

Comment: What about the time needed for the conversion from a list to a set?

Answer (score 2):

Not related to timings or performance, but you may be able to not worry about this kind of thing earlier on by structuring the data differently.

Looking at your previous post, the answer you accepted contained a function `iana_parse` that yielded a dict. So, if you know what you're looking for pre-parse time, then you could do:

```
looking_for = {'ro', 'xx', 'yy', 'zz'}
for res in iana_parse(data): # from previous post
    if res['Subtag'] in looking_for:
        print res['Subtag'], 'was found'
```

Otherwise (or in combination with), you could build a dict from that function and use that:

```
subtag_lookup = {rec['Subtag']:rec for rec in iana_parse(data)}

ro = subtag_lookup['ro']
print ro['Description']
```

At some point if you did just want a list of Subtags, then use:

```
subtags = list(subtag_lookup)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it on yourself. Just use `timeit` module..

[timeit.Timer()](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html#) might be useful for you..

Or, you can also use [time](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) module : -

```
import time
ct = time.clock()
if mytag in tags:
    print "found"
print "diff: ", time.clock() - ct
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer #1. It should offer you the best performance from the choices you presented too as you aren't doing additional processing to your list prior to the comparison.

As for how to test performance... timeit is what you want.

```
import timeit
s1 = """
tags= ['aa', 'ab', 'ae', 'af', 'ak', 'am', 'an', 'ar']
mytag = 'ro'
if mytag in tags:
    print 'found'
"""
s2 = """
tags= ['aa', 'ab', 'ae', 'af', 'ak', 'am', 'an', 'ar']
mytag = 'ro'
if mytag in set(tags):
    print 'found'
"""
s3 = """
tags= ['aa', 'ab', 'ae', 'af', 'ak', 'am', 'an', 'ar']
mytag = 'ro'
if mytag in '|'.join(tags):
    print 'found'
"""

print(timeit.Timer(s1, 'gc.enable()').timeit())
print(timeit.Timer(s2, 'gc.enable()').timeit())
print(timeit.Timer(s3, 'gc.enable()').timeit())

>>> 
0.261634511713
0.476344575019
0.282574283666
```

Comment: For s3 you are timing also the join which might affect the benchmark

Comment: At the second one What is really taking time is initialization of the set object. And the third one is concatenating the strings. You would create those objects only once for multiple values. So arguably those tests would not be fair for second and third one for multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

I've done the tests myself using this code you can use `%cpaste` in IPython console and paste the code bellow.

```
#Get IANA language defs
import urllib
import pprint
import timeit
import IPython
import random
f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry")
#lan.split("%%") .split("\n").split(":")
lan=f.read()
def iana_parse(data):
    for record in data.split("%%\n"):
        # skip empty records at file endings:
        if not record.strip():
            continue
        rec_data = {}
        for line in record.split("\n"):
#            key, value = line.split(":") doesn't work
            key, value = line.partition(':')[::2]
#            key, _, value = line.partition(':')
            rec_data[key.strip()] = value.strip() 
        yield rec_data

tags =[]

for k in iana_parse(lan):
#    print k
    if "Subtag" in k: tags.append(k["Subtag"])
#maybe store it in a shelve http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html

tags_set = set(tags)
tags_str = "|".join(tags)
print "Search 'ro'" 
print "List:"
%timeit 'ro' in tags
print "Set:"
%timeit 'ro' in tags_set
print "String:"
%timeit 'ro' in tags_str

random_tag = tags[random.randint(0,len(tags)-1)]
print "Search random" 
print "List:"
%timeit random_tag in tags 
print "Set:"
%timeit random_tag in tags_set 
print "String:"
%timeit random_tag in tags_str
```

The results are:

```
Search 'ro'
List: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.61 us per loop
Set: 10000000 loops, best of 3: 45.2 ns per loop
String: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 239 ns per loop

Search random
List:10000 loops, best of 3: 36.2 us per loop
Set:10000000 loops, best of 3: 50.9 ns per loop
String:100000 loops, best of 3: 4.88 us per loop
```

So the order is:

1. Set is the fastest, if the initialization of the set from the list is already done and is not included in the measuring.
2. String solution measures the 2nd as speed, also without including the joining in the time measuring.
3. Surprisingly the list is the last.

Answer (score 1):

option #1 should be the fastest for 1-time usage, since it won't even have to go through the whole list (to build a set you need to go through whole list), while #2 will be fastest on all next runs (if you will build set() only once), since it will work under small constant time.